# One side rising faster than other when doing squat unrack

Tags: squats

For some reason, whenever I unrack the squat heavier weights one side of the barbell seems to rise faster than the other during the unracj.  What could be the possible causes?

Comment: Why are you worried about this?

Comment: Feels dangerous...? @ThomasM

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller have you tried actually practicing what your name implies, and just working on the assumption that everything will be ok, rather than assuming that every little minutia is something that will harm you if you don't manipulate it to perfection?

Comment: Ahahahah  oh man, I'm scared to death to get an injury. Medical care is not so good where i live, and that's why I'm trying to figure out how to do everything as perfectly as I cane @DavidScarlett

Comment: @HopefulWhitepiller exercise, in general, is an extremely safe activity, especially in comparison to playing sports, or to living a sedentary lifestyle. About the only thing you need to do to avoid injury when lifting weights is to make sure you never drop the weights on your foot.

Answer (score 1):

As @DavidScarlett wrote in a comment, you need to ease yourself.

Trying to make everything perfectly does two things: 1) It produces stress and facilitates pain, and 2) it sets impossible goals. Let me explain.

1. Stress and pain

Thanks to Moseley, Butler and others we start to realise how much (false) beliefs can modulate and facilitate stress and pain. If you think that a certain movement will lead to injuries, there is a higher chance that you will have pain and protective muscular tension *even if there is no structural reason for that*.

2. impossible goal

I know that people learn to lift with a "straight back" to "protect the spine". Guess what? The measured mean difference in lumbar spine flexion between people who try to keep their back straight and people  who bow down to lift is 10 degrees. That's 2 degrees per segment. Add the fact that even within a single set of 5 or 12, no two executions will be exactly the same. See where this is going? Perfect form is an illusion. You should lift in a way you feel comfortable with and that does not produce lasting pain, with a slow load progression over considerable time to give your bones and connective tissue time to catch up with the considerably (about 3 times) faster (neuro-)muscular adaptation to training. As long as you keep symmetry and the weight in the centre of your support area (between your feet), your body will adapt and align itself according to its abilities.

Now, what about your described "problem"? It could be that your current neuromuscular status is simply asymmetrical. It could be a thousand other reasons. That is exactly what you address through training. Just take care to keep a roughly symmetrical form. If you can't, the load may be too much for your weaker side.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it was due to my poor unrack. So, the thing is, when you unrack the squat, you actually want to make your stance narrow. When you step back, step back so that the stance is of appropriate width again. The concept is well discussed  [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXvZSqtmBDI)